# swift new view displays old data

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Hello so I have a main view and from that view you can click on different elements. Every element will open a new presentation specific to the element chosen, kind of like clicking on a tweet and seeing the comments page. So when I run the simulator, clicking on an element will present the comments view specific to that element, but when I close it and press on a different element, it presents the data for the old element and not the new one, I think the comments array is not getting updated, not sure why anyone know.

comment view

```
struct CommentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = CommentViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var tweet: Tweet
    @State var selectedTweet: Tweet
    
    init(tweet: Tweet){
        self.tweet = tweet
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                ScrollView {
                        ForEach(viewModel.tweets){ tweet in
                            Button{
                                selectedTweet = tweet
                                showNewCommentView.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                TweetRowView(tweet: tweet, hasDivider: true)
                                    .padding()
                            }
                        }
                        .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedTweet) { tweet in
                            CommentView(tweet: tweet)
                        }
                }
                
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                }
                 
            }
             
        }
        .onAppear{
            viewModel.getComments(withTweet: tweet)
        }
    }
}
```

viewModel

```
class CommentViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var comments = [Comment]()
    let service = TweetService()

    func getComments(withTweet tweet: Tweet){
        service.getComments(tweet: tweet) { comments in
            self.comments = comments
        }
    }
}
```

parent view

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State private var showNewCommentView = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack{
                        ForEach(viewModel.tweets){ tweet in
                            Button{
                                showNewCommentView.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                TweetRowView(tweet: tweet, hasDivider: true)
                                    .padding()
                            }
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNewCommentView){
                                CommentView(tweet: tweet)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, where you use `.fullScreenCover(item: ...)` outside the `ForEach`. Works for me.

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State var selectedTweet: Tweet?  // <-- here
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack{
                    ForEach(viewModel.tweets){ tweet in
                        Button{
                            selectedTweet = tweet  // <-- here
                        } label: {
                            TweetRowView(tweet: tweet, hasDivider: true)
                            .padding()
                        }
                    }
                    // -- here outside the ForEach
                    .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedTweet) { tweet in
                        CommentView(tweet: tweet)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, when I try your example I get an error on the $selectedTweet saying "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Tweet>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Item?>" any thoughts on why this is

Comment: can you show the code you are using (edit your question). The line of code you get the error and the full error message.

Comment: Ive updated my comment view and the error I'm getting is on $selectedtweet and it says Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Tweet>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Item?>'

Comment: Look at my answer carefully, I present the code for `FeedView`, not as you have done in `CommentView`.
Put the original `CommentView` back on, and replace your `FeedView` with my code.